# Syntax Highlighting for Greater Golf!

Tags: code-golf, string

Golfers.

Together, we have banded together to produce code that is concise, is functionally beautiful and is uglier then the Phantom of the Opera from the original novel.

The time has come for us to bring beauty back to the world of programming. With color. In a way that is concise, functionally beautiful is uglier then the Phantom of the Opera from the original novel.

We're gonna be coding a colorful syntax highlighter. In the shortest amount of code possible.

You will receive via an input file or Stdin a valid C file. The C file will use the line convention of your choice, and will only contain ASCII characters 32-126. You have to turn it into a HTML file that displays correctly at least in Chrome, that shows the source code  with syntax highlighting. The output may be in a file or to Stdout.

You must highlight:

- All strings and characters (including the quote characters) in Green (#00FF00). The strings may contain escaped characters.
- All C reserved words in Blue (#0000FF).
- All comments in Yellow (#FFFF00).
- All C preprocessor directives in Pink (#FF00FF).

The output when displayed in Chrome must:

- Be in a fixed-width font
- Display new lines wherever they appeared in the original source
- Accurately reproduce whitespace. A tab character should be taken as being 4 spaces.

**Bonuses**

- x 0.9 if you include line numbers. Line numbers must be able to reach at least 99999. All source must still be aligned - so, source code with smaller line numbers should still start at the same position as source code with higher line numbers
- x 0.8 if background of each line is alternated between light gray (#C0C0C0) and white (#FFFFFF)
- x 0.9 if your source code is written in C, and can correctly format itself.

**Scoring**

This is code golf. Your score is the amount of bytes of your source code multiplied by any bonuses. The winner is the golfer with the lowest score.

Comment: what if a preprocessor directive includes a reserved word?  What if a string or comment includes a reserved word?

Comment: @Charles the standard behaviour of the bigger IDE's is, that comments will not be further highlighted, meaning comments stay comments. haven't been working with preprocessor directives much, but wikipedia also here does not further highlight code... also strings are strings, they need no further evaluation...

Comment: Confirming what Vogel612 says is the correct behaviour

Comment: "valid at least in Chrome", or "displays correctly at least in Chrome"?

Comment: Displays correctly. Editing now.

Comment: I think there should be a bonus if you write this thing in C.

Comment: Actually... so did I - providing that it could highlight itself. I was concerned non-c folk might think it unfair. Does a x 0.9 sound fair?

Comment: I think so.  That seems like a fair amount.

Comment: "Your score is the amount of bytes of your source code multiplied by any bonuses." Um? Doesn't this mean your score will be higher if you use more characters? If lower means better, doesn't getting bonuses then make your score worse?

Comment: @Trimsty Wait a second, I'm an idiot. xD Nevermind.

Comment: Worst colors ever!

Answer (score 8):

### Perl 769 chars * 0.9 * 0.8 = 554

Probably still some improvements to be made on some of the regexes, but it's slowly getting there!

```pl
$_=join"",<>;$s="<tt class";$c="</tt>";$d=counter;$e=color;s/\t/    /g;s!<!&lt;!g;s!>!&gt;!g;s!^#.+(?=$|
)!$s=d>$&$c!gm;s!//.+!$s=c>$&$c!g;s|(['"]).*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\1|($h=$&)=~s!/!&#47;!g;"$s=s>$h$c"|smeg;s!/\*.*?\*/!$s=c>$&$c!smg;s!\b(_Packed|(au|go)to|break|c(ase|har|onst|ontinue)|d(efault|o|ouble)|e(lse|num|xtern)|f(loat|or)|if|int|long|re(gister|turn)|short|(un)?signed|s(izeof|tatic|truct|witch)|typedef|union|vo(id|latile)|while)\b!$s=r>$&$c!g;s!=(\w)>.+?$c!join"$c
$s=$1>",split$/,$&!smeg;s!
!<tr><td>!g;print"<style>body{font:10px monospace;$d-reset:n}td{white-space:pre}tr:nth-child(even){background:#c0c0c0}tr:before{$d-increment:n;content:$d(n)}.d{$e:#f0f}.r{$e:#00f}.c{$e:#ff0}.s{$e:#0f0}tt tt{$e:inherit!important}</style><table cellspacing=0><tr><td>$_"
```

Slightly less obfuscated version with comments:

```pl
$_=join"",<>; # slurp file
$s="<tt class"; # used later - use <tt/> instead of <span/>, fewer chars!
$c="</tt>";
$d=counter;
$e=color;
s/\t/    /g; # convert tabs to spaces
s!<!&lt;!g; # htmlentity < and >
s!>!&gt;!g;
s!^#.+(?=$|\n)!$s=d>$&$c!gm; # directives
s!//.+!$s=c>$&$c!g; # inline comments
s|(['"]).*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\1|($h=$&)=~s!/!&#47;!g;"$s=s>$h$c"|smeg; # strings, might have 0 length - thanks @Einacio; work-around string that contain /* by converting them to HTML entities
s!/\*.*?\*/!$s=c>$&$c!smg; # multi-line comments
s!\b(_Packed|(au|go)to|break|c(ase|har|onst|ontinue)|d(efault|o|ouble)|e(lse|num|xtern)|f(loat|or)|if|int|long|re(gister|turn)|short|(un)?signed|s(izeof|tatic|truct|witch)|typedef|union|vo(id|latile)|while)\b!$s=r>$&$c!g; # reserved words, don't optimise this too much! - thanks @bwoebi
s!=(\w)>.+?$c!join"$c
$s=$1>",split$/,$&!smeg; # any multi-line string/comment, ensure <span/>s are repeated
s!\n!<tr><td>!g; # strip newlines, replace with <tr><td>, don't need </td> _or_ </tr> - thanks @xfix!
print"<style>
body{font:10px monospace;$d-reset:n} /* init counter */
td{white-space:pre} /* preserve whitespace */
tr:nth-child(odd){background:#c0c0c0} /* alternating rows */
tr:before{$d-increment:n;content:$d(n)} /* place counter */
.d{$e:#f0f} /* highlights */
.r{$e:#00f}
.c{$e:#ff0}
.s{$e:#0f0}
tt tt{$e:inherit!important} /* ignore reserved words/comments in strings */
</style><table cellspacing=0><tr><td>$_"
```

Now successfully highlights @xfix's entry.

Borrowed the idea to drop `</tr>` from @xfix's entry, thank you!

[Example of output for @xfix's solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ydMc9/3/).

Comment: Your solution cannot highlight my solution correctly, because it doesn't escape HTML markup, and doesn't show whitespace properly.

Comment: Ahhh! I forgot `white-space: pre`, I'll get that added and work on some other escaping. Still much to be done on this I feel!

Comment: In HTML5, `</tr>` and `</td>` are completely optional, so I simply ignored them.

Comment: You actually could save some chars by using sometimes the full keyword name in regex. E.g. `if|int` is one char less than `i(f|nt)`. Or `d(efault|o|ouble)` is another char less than `d(efault|o(uble)?)`.

Comment: on the fiddle the '\\' on line 61 is not marked as string. is an error of the example or an edge case failing?

Comment: @xfix, I'm sure I should have known that! Thank you!

Comment: @bwoebi, you're right! Trying to group too much, I'll update shortly, thank you!

Comment: @Einacio, I think it's an oversight, well spotted! I'll get on to that as well! Thanks!

Comment: The code will still work if you move the `<style>` block to the end and omit the end tag. You can then also omit the last `}` of the style. Sure, it's completely invalid, but it works in Chrome!

Comment: Thanks @user2428118! Updated, a lot to do to get close to the PHP one though...

Answer (score 7):

## C - <del>1605</del> 1200 chars * 0.9 * 0.8 * 0.9 = 777 chars

Definitely too long, but whatever. 264 used by list of keywords itself. The long one liner version. Doesn't use memory allocations, so the memory usage is very low (and everything is global, so the stack is not really used). [Sample HTML on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgfJ9/). In my opinion, comments support was most complex thing in the code.

```
char*k[]={"auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default","do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto","if","int","long","register","return","short","signed","sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union","unsigned","void","volatile","while"},b[9];c;p;e;p;l=1;q;s;i;main(){printf("<style>tr:nth-child(2n){background:#C0C0C0}</style><table style=font-family:monospace;white-space:pre-wrap><tr><td>1<td>");while(~(c=getchar())){if(!e&&q){if(q==c){printf("%c</span>",c);q=0;continue;}}else if(isalpha(c)&&p<8){b[p++]=c;continue;}else if(b[0]){for(i=0;i<32;i++){s!=2&&!strcmp(k[i],b)&&(printf("<span style=color:#00F>%s</span>",b),b[0]=0);}printf("%s",b);memset(b,0,9);}p=0;switch(c){case'<':printf("&lt;");goto e;case'&':printf("&amp;");goto e;case 92:putchar(c);e^=1;goto e;case'/':q||1==s?putchar('/'):3==s?(printf("*/"),s=0):(s=1);break;case'*':if(s==1){s=2;printf("<span style=color:#FF0>/*");}else if(s==2){s=3;}else{goto d;}break;case 39:case'"':e||q||(q=c,printf("<span style=color:#0F0>"));e=0;goto d;case 10:l+=1;printf("<tr><td>%d<td>",l);if(p&&e){case'#':e=0;q||(p=1,printf("<span style=color:#F0F>"));}else{p=0;}default:d:10!=c&&putchar(c);e:s=s/2*2;}}puts(b);}
```

And the longer version (which is as readable as real program, aside of few code golf tricks I didn't think I could apply easily while golfing the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof *(array))
/* Sample comment. */
int main(void) {
    const char *keywords[] = {
        "auto",     "break",    "case",     "char",     "const",
        "continue", "default",  "do",       "double",   "else",
        "enum",     "extern",   "float",    "for",      "goto",
        "if",       "int",      "long",     "register", "return",
        "short",    "signed",   "sizeof",   "static",   "struct",
        "switch",   "typedef",  "union",    "unsigned", "void",
        "volatile", "while",
    };
    int character;
    int preprocessor = 0;
    int escape = 0;
    char buffer[9] = {0};
    int pos = 0;
    int line = 1;
    int quote = 0;
    int comment_state = 0;
    printf("<style>tr:nth-child(2n){background:#C0C0C0}</style><table style=font-family:monospace;white-space:pre-wrap><tr><td>1<td>");
    while ((character = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!escape && quote) {
            if (quote == character) {
                printf("%c</span>", character);
                quote = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (isalpha(character) && pos < 8) {
            buffer[pos] = character;
            pos += 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if (buffer[0]) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(keywords); i++) {
                if (comment_state != 2 && strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0) {
                    printf("<span style=color:#00F>%s</span>", buffer);
                    buffer[0] = 0;
                }
            }
            printf("%s", buffer);
            memset(buffer, 0, 9);
        }
        pos = 0;
        switch (character) {
        case '<':
            printf("&lt;");
            goto e;
        case '&':
            printf("&amp;");
            goto e;
        case '\\':
            putchar(character);
            escape ^= 1;
            goto e;
        case '/':
            if (quote || comment_state == 1) {
                putchar('/');
            }
            else if (comment_state == 3) {
                printf("*/");
                comment_state = 0;
            }
            else {
                comment_state = 1;
            }
            break;
        case '*':
            if (comment_state == 1) {
                comment_state = 2;
                printf("<span style=color:#FF0>/*");
            }
            else if (comment_state == 2) {
                comment_state = 3;
            }
            else {
                goto d;
            }
            break;
        case '\'':
        case '"':
            if (!escape && !quote) {
                quote = character;
                printf("<span style=color:#0F0>");
            }
            escape = 0;
            goto d;
        case '\n':
            line += 1;
            printf("<tr><td>%d<td>", line);

            /* Execute next only if conditions match. */
            if (preprocessor && escape) {
        case '#':
                escape = 0;
                if (!quote) {
                    preprocessor = 1;
                    printf("<span style=color:#F0F>");
                }
            }
            else {
                preprocessor = 0;
            }
            /* fallthru */
        default:
        d:
            if (character != '\n') putchar(character);
        e:
            comment_state = comment_state / 2 * 2;
        }
    }
    printf("%s</table>", buffer);
}
```

Comment: The output looks fantastic!

Comment: @lochok: And it's now shortened to 1200 bytes. This is still longer than Perl solution, but now the gap is smaller.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work with multiline comments.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP 606 bytes × 0.9 × 0.8 = 436

```php
<style>li:nth-child(odd){background:#f5f5f5}pre{tab-size:4;-moz-tab-size:4}</style><pre><ol><li><?php $p='preg_match';preg_match_all('_\w+|("|\')(\\\\?.)*?\1|#(.(?!/[/*]))*|//.*|(?s)/\*.*?\*/|.+?_',stream_get_contents(STDIN),$m);foreach($m[0]as$t)echo'</font><font color=#',$t[0]=='#'?'d0d':($p('_^/[/*]_',$t)?'bb0':($p('/"|\'/',$t)?'0d0':($p('/^(auto|break|(cas|continu|doubl|els|volatil|whil)e|char|(cons|defaul|floa|in|shor|struc)t|do|enum|extern|for|goto|if|long|register|return|sizeof|static|switch|typedef|union|(un|)signed|void)$/',$t)?'00f':0))),'>'.preg_replace("/\r?\n/",'<li>',htmlentities($t));
```

Formatted:

```php
<style>li:nth-child(odd){background:#f5f5f5}pre{tab-size:4;-moz-tab-size:4}</style>
<pre><ol><li><?php
$p='preg_match';
preg_match_all('_\w+|("|\')(\\\\?.)*?\1|#(.(?!/[/*]))*|//.*|(?s)/\*.*?\*/|.+?_',
    stream_get_contents(STDIN),$m);
foreach($m[0]as$t)
    echo'</font><font color=#',
        $t[0]=='#'?'d0d':(
        $p('_^/[/*]_',$t)?'bb0':(
        $p('/"|\'/',$t)?'0d0':(
        $p('/^(auto|break|(cas|continu|doubl|els|volatil|whil)e|char|'.
        '(cons|defaul|floa|in|shor|struc)t|do|enum|extern|for|goto|if|long|register|'.
        'return|sizeof|static|switch|typedef|union|(un|)signed|void)$/',$t)?'00f':
        0))),
        '>'.preg_replace("/\r?\n/",'<li>',htmlentities($t));
```

- Reads from stdin and writes to stdout.
- Accepted line endings are \n and \r\n.
- Does line numbers and line color alternation.
- I used *slightly* different colors so I could bear to look at it, though not in a way that affects the byte count.
- I don't have Chrome to test it although it's fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

### C++ - <strike>5067 bytes</strike>4612 * 0.9 * 0.8 = 3320 (* 0.9 = 2988 if being able to format itself counts - it's written in C++)

I realize that this is larger than the solutions already presented here, but I've decided to post this anyway because I started working on my version before the C solution by xfix was posted.

- It works with multiline comments
- It outputs HTML that has errors (but it displays correctly in Chrome)
- It reads out of input.c and produces output.html

A half of this is the large array of C and C++ keywords.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#define B break
#define Z(a,b)if(s[i]==a){z=b;o+=OP+p(s[i]);i++;B;}
#define V(a,b)if(e(s,i,a)){z=b;o+=OC+p(s.substr(i,2));i+=2;B;}
#define N(a) if(s[i]=='\n'){a;o+=nl();i++;B;}
#define Q(a)if(e(s,i,"\\")){o+=p(s.substr(i,2));i+=2;B;}if(s[i]==a){z=0;o+=p(s[i])+CL;i++;B;}
#define C case
using namespace std;string k[]={"__abstract","__alignof","_Alignas","_alignof","and","and_eq","__asm","_asm","asm","__assume","_assume","auto","__based","_based","bitand","bitor","bool","_Bool","__box","break","__builtin_alignof","_builtin_alignof","__builtin_isfloat","case","catch","__cdecl","_cdecl","_Complex","cdecl","char","class","__compileBreak","_compileBreak","compl","const","const_cast","continue","__declspec","_declspec","default","__delegate","delete","do","double","dynamic_cast","else","enum","__event","__except","_except","explicit","__export","_export","extern","false","__far","_far","far","__far16","_far16","__fastcall","_fastcall","__feacpBreak","_feacpBreak","__finally","_finally","float","for","__forceinline","_forceinline","__fortran","_fortran","fortran","friend","_Generic","__gc","goto","__hook","__huge","_huge","huge","_Imaginary","__identifier","if","__if_exists","__if_not_exists","__inline","_inline","inline","int","__int128","__int16","_int16","__int32","_int32","__int64","_int64","__int8","_int8","__interface","__leave","_leave","long","__multiple_inheritance","_multiple_inheritance","mutable","namespace","__near","_near","near","new","_Noreturn","__nodefault","__nogc","__nontemporal","not","not_eq","__nounwind","__novtordisp","_novtordisp","operator","or","or_eq","__pascal","_pascal","pascal","__pin","__pragma","_pragma","private","__probability","__property","protected","__ptr32","_ptr32","__ptr64","_ptr64","public","__raise","register","reinterpret_cast","restrict","__restrict","__resume","return","__sealed","__serializable","_serializable","short","signed","__single_inheritance","_single_inheritance","sizeof","static","static_cast","_Static_assert","__stdcall","_stdcall","struct","__super","switch","__sysapi","__syscall","_syscall","template","this","__thiscall","_thiscall","throw","_Thread_local","__transient","_transient","true","__try","_try","try","__try_cast","typedef","typeid","typename","__typeof","__unaligned","__unhook","union","unsigned","using","__uuidof","_uuidof","__value","virtual","__virtual_inheritance","_virtual_inheritance","void","volatile","__w64","_w64","__wchar_t","wchar_t","while","xor","xor_eq"};string OS="<font color=\"#00FF00\">";string OC="<font color=\"#FFFF00\">";string OK="<font color=\"#0000FF\">";string OP="<font color=\"#FF00FF\">";string CL="</font>";string NL[]={ "<li class=\"li l1\">","<li class=\"li l2\">" };bool lo=1;string nl() {lo=!lo;return "</li>"+NL[lo];}bool r(char c,string s) {for (size_t i=0; i<s.size(); i++)if (c==s[i])return 0;return 0;}bool is(string s,int i) {return !(i<0||i>=s.size())&&((s[i]=='_')||isalpha(s[i]));}bool ic(string s,int i){return !(i<0||i>=s.size())&&(is(s,i)||('0'<=s[i]&&s[i]<='9'));}bool e(string a,int s,string b) {return !(a.size()-s<b.size())&&a.substr(s,b.size())==b;}string p(char c) {switch (c) {C  '&':return "&amp;";C  '\"':return "&quot;";C  '\'':return "&apos;";C  '<':return "&lt;";C  '>':return "&gt;";}stringstream s;s<<c;return s.str();}string p(string s) {string ans="";for (size_t i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {ans+=p(s[i]);}return ans;}string h(string s) {int z=0;size_t i=0;string o ="<html><body><style type=\"text/css\">.l{list-style-type: decimal;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} .li{display:list-item;word-wrap:B-word;} .l1{background-color:#FFFFFF;} .l2{background-color:#EEEEEE;} .cd{white-space:pre;}</style><code class=\"cd\"><ul class=\"l\">";o+=NL[1];for (; i<s.size();) {switch (z) {C 0:{Z('#',6)Z('"',3)Z('\'',2)V("//",4)V("/*",5)N()for (size_t j=0; j<201; j++)if (e(s,i,k[j])&&!ic(s,i+k[j].size())) {o+=OK+p(k[j])+CL;i+=k[j].size();B;}if (is(s,i)) {z=7;o+=p(s[i]);i++;if (i+1==s.size()||!ic(s,i+1)) {z=0;}B;}o+=p(s[i]);i++;B;}o+=p(s[i]);i++;B;C  2:Q('\'')C  3:Q('"')C 4:{N(z=0)o+=p(s[i]); i++;B;}C 5:{if (e(s,i,"*/")) {z=0;o+=p(s.substr(i,2))+CL;i+=2;B;}N()o+=p(s[i]);i++;B;}C 6:{if (s[i]=='\n') {int j=i-1;for (; j>=0&&r(s[j],"\n\t "); j--);if (j<0||s[j] != '\\') {z=0;o+=CL+nl();i++;B;}o+=nl();i++;B;}o+=p(s[i]);i++;B;}C 7:{if (i+1==s.size()||!ic(s,i+1)) {z=0;}o+=p(s[i]);i++;B;}}}o+="</ul></code>";return o;}int main() {ifstream i("input.c");ofstream o("output.html");string cCode((istreambuf_iterator<char>(i)),istreambuf_iterator<char>());o<<h(cCode)<<endl;}
```

Readable version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//The 201 keywords from C and C++. Not sure if all of them are listed here!
const size_t NUMBER_OF_KEYWORDS = 201;
string keywords[] = { "__abstract", "__alignof", "_Alignas", "_alignof", "and",
        "and_eq", "__asm", "_asm", "asm", "__assume", "_assume", "auto",
        "__based", "_based", "bitand", "bitor", "bool", "_Bool", "__box",
        "break", "__builtin_alignof", "_builtin_alignof", "__builtin_isfloat",
        "case", "catch", "__cdecl", "_cdecl", "_Complex", "cdecl", "char",
        "class", "__compileBreak", "_compileBreak", "compl", "const",
        "const_cast", "continue", "__declspec", "_declspec", "default",
        "__delegate", "delete", "do", "double", "dynamic_cast", "else", "enum",
        "__event", "__except", "_except", "explicit", "__export", "_export",
        "extern", "false", "__far", "_far", "far", "__far16", "_far16",
        "__fastcall", "_fastcall", "__feacpBreak", "_feacpBreak", "__finally",
        "_finally", "float", "for", "__forceinline", "_forceinline",
        "__fortran", "_fortran", "fortran", "friend", "_Generic", "__gc",
        "goto", "__hook", "__huge", "_huge", "huge", "_Imaginary",
        "__identifier", "if", "__if_exists", "__if_not_exists", "__inline",
        "_inline", "inline", "int", "__int128", "__int16", "_int16", "__int32",
        "_int32", "__int64", "_int64", "__int8", "_int8", "__interface",
        "__leave", "_leave", "long", "__multiple_inheritance",
        "_multiple_inheritance", "mutable", "namespace", "__near", "_near",
        "near", "new", "_Noreturn", "__nodefault", "__nogc", "__nontemporal",
        "not", "not_eq", "__nounwind", "__novtordisp", "_novtordisp",
        "operator", "or", "or_eq", "__pascal", "_pascal", "pascal", "__pin",
        "__pragma", "_pragma", "private", "__probability", "__property",
        "protected", "__ptr32", "_ptr32", "__ptr64", "_ptr64", "public",
        "__raise", "register", "reinterpret_cast", "restrict", "__restrict",
        "__resume", "return", "__sealed", "__serializable", "_serializable",
        "short", "signed", "__single_inheritance", "_single_inheritance",
        "sizeof", "static", "static_cast", "_Static_assert", "__stdcall",
        "_stdcall", "struct", "__super", "switch", "__sysapi", "__syscall",
        "_syscall", "template", "this", "__thiscall", "_thiscall", "throw",
        "_Thread_local", "__transient", "_transient", "true", "__try", "_try",
        "try", "__try_cast", "typedef", "typeid", "typename", "__typeof",
        "__unaligned", "__unhook", "union", "unsigned", "using", "__uuidof",
        "_uuidof", "__value", "virtual", "__virtual_inheritance",
        "_virtual_inheritance", "void", "volatile", "__w64", "_w64",
        "__wchar_t", "wchar_t", "while", "xor", "xor_eq" };

// Different states
const int NONE = 0;
const int WHITESPACE = 1;
const int CHAR_UNCLOSED = 2;
const int STRING_UNCLOSED = 3;
const int LINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED = 4;
const int MULTILINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED = 5;
const int PREPROCESSOR_UNCLOSED = 6;
const int IDENTIFIER = 7;

//Different elements
const string OPEN_STRING = "<font color=\"#00FF00\">";
const string CLOSE_STRING = "</font>";
const string OPEN_COMMENT = "<font color=\"#FFFF00\">";
const string CLOSE_COMMENT = "</font>";
const string OPEN_KEYWORD = "<font color=\"#0000FF\">";
const string CLOSE_KEYWORD = "</font>";
const string OPEN_PREPROCESSOR = "<font color=\"#FF00FF\">";
const string CLOSE_PREPROCESSOR = "</font>";

//Alternating background
const string NEW_LINE[] = { "<li class=\"li l1\">", "<li class=\"li l2\">" };
bool lineOdd = true;
string getNewLineHTML() {
    lineOdd = !lineOdd;
    return "</li>" + NEW_LINE[lineOdd];
}

//Check if the character is in the string chars
bool inRange(char c, string chars) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++)
        if (c == chars[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}

//Check if the character is the start of an identifier
bool isIdentifierStart(string input, int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= input.size())
        return false;
    return (input[i] == '_') || ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z')
            || ('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z');
}
//Check if the character is the continuation of an identifier
bool isIdentifierCont(string input, int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= input.size())
        return false;
    return ('0' <= input[i] && input[i] <= '9') || isIdentifierStart(input, i);
}
//Check if a[start + i] == b[i], i<b.size()
bool eqRange(string a, int start, string b) {
    if (a.size() - start < b.size())
        return false;
    return a.substr(start, b.size()) == b;
}
//Escape the sourcecode for HTML
string escape(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case '&':
        return "&amp;";
    case '\"':
        return "&quot;";
    case '\'':
        return "&apos;";
    case '<':
        return "&lt;";
    case '>':
        return "&gt;";
    }
    //Is there a better way to do this?
    stringstream strm;
    strm << c;
    return strm.str();
}
string escape(string str) {
    string ans = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        ans += escape(str[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}
string highlight(string input) {
    //The current state
    int state = NONE;
    //The current position
    size_t i = 0;
    //Styles
    string output =
            "<html><body><style type=\"text/css\">.l{list-style-type: decimal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;} .li{ display: list-item; word-wrap: break-word;} .l1{background-color: #FFFFFF;} .l2{background-color: #EEEEEE;} .cd{white-space: pre;}</style><code class=\"cd\"><ul class=\"l\">";
    output += NEW_LINE[1];
    for (; i < input.size();) {
        switch (state) {
        case NONE: {
            if (input[i] == '#') { //Start a preprocessor statement
                state = PREPROCESSOR_UNCLOSED;
                output += OPEN_PREPROCESSOR + escape(input[i]);
                i++;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '"') { //Start a string
                state = STRING_UNCLOSED;
                output += OPEN_STRING + escape(input[i]);
                i++;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '\'') { //Start a character
                state = CHAR_UNCLOSED;
                output += OPEN_STRING + escape(input[i]);
                i++;
                break;
            }
            if (eqRange(input, i, "//")) { //Start a single line comment
                state = LINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED;
                output += OPEN_COMMENT + escape(input.substr(i, 2));
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
            if (eqRange(input, i, "/*")) { //Start a multi-line comment
                state = MULTILINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED;
                output += OPEN_COMMENT + escape(input.substr(i, 2));
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '\n') { //New lines are special!
                output += getNewLineHTML();
                i++;
                break;
            }
            for (size_t j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_KEYWORDS; j++) //Iterate through keywords
                if (eqRange(input, i, keywords[j])
                        && !isIdentifierCont(input, i + keywords[j].size())) { // The keyword can't be a prefix of an identifier, so test for that
                    output += OPEN_KEYWORD + escape(keywords[j])
                            + CLOSE_KEYWORD;
                    i += keywords[j].size();
                    break;
                }
            //Treat identifiers separately because we need to separate identifiers from keywords.
            if (isIdentifierStart(input, i)) {
                state = IDENTIFIER;
                output += escape(input[i]);
                i++;
                //If the next character is not a part of the identifier, go to the NONE state
                if (i + 1 == input.size() || !isIdentifierCont(input, i + 1)) {
                    state = NONE;
                }
                break;
            }
            //Other characters
            output += escape(input[i]);
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case CHAR_UNCLOSED: {
            if (eqRange(input, i, "\\")) { //Treat escape sequences inside quotes
                output += escape(input.substr(i, 2));
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '\'') { //Close quote
                state = NONE;
                output += escape(input[i]) + CLOSE_STRING;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]); //Other characters go into the literal
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case STRING_UNCLOSED: {
            if (eqRange(input, i, "\\")) { //Treat escape sequences inside quotes
                output += escape(input.substr(i, 2));
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '"') { //Close quote
                state = NONE;
                output += escape(input[i]) + CLOSE_STRING;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]); //Other characters go into the literal
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case LINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED: {
            if (input[i] == '\n') { //Close comment with new line
                state = NONE;
                output += CLOSE_COMMENT + getNewLineHTML();
                i++;
                break;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]); //Comment body
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case MULTILINE_COMMENT_UNCLOSED: {
            if (eqRange(input, i, "*/")) { //Close multiline comment
                state = NONE;
                output += escape(input.substr(i, 2)) + CLOSE_COMMENT;
                i += 2;
                break;
            }
            if (input[i] == '\n') { //New lines are special!
                output += getNewLineHTML();
                i++;
                break;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]); //Comment body
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case PREPROCESSOR_UNCLOSED: {
            if (input[i] == '\n') { //Close preprocessor statement or go to next line
                int j = i - 1;
                for (; j >= 0 && inRange(input[j], "\n\t "); j--)
                    //Seek las non-whitespace character
                    ;
                if (j < 0 || input[j] != '\\') { //Check if the last non-whitespace character is a backslash
                    state = NONE; //... If it isn't, close the preprocessor statement
                    output += CLOSE_PREPROCESSOR + getNewLineHTML();
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
                output += getNewLineHTML(); //... If it is, we need to extend the preprocessor statement to the next line
                i++;
                break;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]);
            i++;
            break;
        }
        case IDENTIFIER: {
            //If the next character is not a part of the identifier, go to the NONE state
            if (i + 1 == input.size() || !isIdentifierCont(input, i + 1)) {
                state = NONE;
            }
            output += escape(input[i]);
            i++;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    output += "</ul></code>";
    return output;
}
int main() {
    ifstream input("input.c");
    ofstream output("output.html");
    std::string cCode((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    output << highlight(cCode) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary to highlight compiler keywords. They aren't standard. But if you really want to, assume anything starting with `__` (two underscores) to be a keyword, as specification says that it reserved for implementation purposes.